# Full Screen Background Image - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a 1 page site with full screen scrolling sections.
Each section displays correctly on desktop, but on mobile the 'team' section has a white block top and bottom.

I have made another section for teams ('team2test') for use only on mobile - with HTML to try to make the section full height but the background image is not full screen

Please assist in either why the 'team' section has a gap top and bottom - or why my background image is not full screen in 'team2test'

Code for 'team2Test':

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.team-images-mobile {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.team-section {
  background-image: url(https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/team_7693a7d4f435b52cec2b4ce8cbbf00a4.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-section">

  <div class="team-images-mobile">
    <img src="https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/MAX-300x300.png" alt="" >
    <img src="https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/KRISH-300x300.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/COFIELD-300x300.png" alt="">
  </div>


</div>
```

[Link to site](https://neuefund.com/)

[image: white gaps on mobile]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from:

1. **why the 'team' section has a gap top and bottom**

That comes from your padding in

```
.team-images-mobile {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

2. **why my background image is not full screen**

This come from the `height: 100vh` you set in `.team-section`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.team-images-mobile {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.team-section {
  background-image: url(https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/team_7693a7d4f435b52cec2b4ce8cbbf00a4.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.team-section img {
    width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-section">

  <div class="team-images-mobile">
    <img src="https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/MAX-300x300.png" alt="" >
    <img src="https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/KRISH-300x300.png" alt="">
    <img src="https://neuefund.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/COFIELD-300x300.png" alt="">
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: the above does make the section full height - but now I have this white gap on mobile top and bottom on my "team" section which the other sections do not have - kindly see screenshot added to my original question

Answer (score 0):

The HTML of your "Team section" looks like this now:

```html
<div class="grve-column wpb_column grve-column-1">
    <div class="grve-column-wrapper">
        <div class="grve-element grve-text">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Team</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="team-section">
                    <div class="team-images-mobile">
                       ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grve-empty-space grve-height-1x" style=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you check in your [browser inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector), you'd find that the `.grve-element` (the heading text "Team") is taking up space before the actual `.team-section` in your code. And that element has a white background.

So it doesn't really matter with your `.team-section` style. It's more of an HTML structure issue.

There are 2 direction to solve this:

1. If you can control the overall HTML, simply move your .team-section background css settings to the `.grve-column` level; or
2. Make `.grve-element` height 0 by setting it as "position: absolute; width: 100%;". You'd need to give `.team-images-mobile` some padding so they won't overlap with "Team".

Comment: I have put the class "team-section" on the column section of visual composer - and moved my h2 "team" inside the "team-section html" container. see screenshot on mobile - these white gaps top and bottom keep appearing - see screenshot added to my original question

Comment: -Yeung .. this gap does not appear on mobile on the other sections. only "TEAM" and "Team2Test".

Comment: @Anna: I've just went to the site. And I don't see the gap you mentioned. Did you fix the issue already?

Comment: no, I have not fixed it - I just removed the "team2test" section. but the initial problem on the "TEAM" section is still displaying on my mobile devices as per the screenshot above.  The white gap is above and below the section and does not show on mobile testers, but only on mobile devices.   yes this gap is not on any other section - and only the "Team" section? :)

Comment: What device are you using? What operating system? And what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using an iPhone11ProMax, with iOS 15.1.  Safari. 
If I remove the post grid of images for 'Team' - the gap goes away, but if i insert either an image or my post grid back into the section - the gap returns.

Comment: What do you mean by "post grid"? Is it there now?

Comment: Yes it is there now.  The 3 images of the team in the team section are being displayed using a 'post grid' in visual composer.   I have tried replacing the post grid with an html block displaying the images (as previously in team2test section) but the gap still appears. Are you able to see this gap on your mobile device? It does not show on the mobile browser testers which makes it difficult to 'inspect'.